How do I determine what order of operation the borrow checker will accept?
I'm currently learning Rust and having problem understanding why borrowing requires certain order of operation.
E.g. this code works:
fn add<'a>(todo: &'a mut Vec<&'a str>, task: &'a str) {
    todo.insert(0, task);
}

fn remove(todo: &mut Vec<&str>) {
    todo.pop();
}

fn main() {
    let mut todo = vec!["eat", "sleep"];
    remove(&mut todo);
    add(&mut todo, "learn rust");
}

But if I switch the order of add and remove, it fails to compile:
fn main() {
    let mut todo = vec!["eat", "sleep"];
    add(&mut todo, "learn rust");
    remove(&mut todo);
}

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `todo` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:12:12
   |
11 |     add(&mut todo, "learn rust");
   |         --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
12 |     remove(&mut todo);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            second mutable borrow occurs here
   |            first borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.

Even if I separate the add and remove in each own scope, it will still fail:
fn main() {
    let mut todo = vec!["eat", "sleep"];
    {
        add(&mut todo, "learn rust");
    }
    {
        remove(&mut todo);
    }
}
//  No effect, same error

Why can't I do add first? The end result in the above case should be the same, so why does the order of operations matter?
rustc --explain E0499 says A variable was borrowed as mutable more than once then why does it work if I do remove first then add? Doesn't it also borrow-as-mutable more than once?

&'a mut T<'a> is always wrong.

StackOverflow will have so many fewer Rust questions once #120481 is resolved.

@eggyal I wish a one that would detect self-referential struct... To be honest, I think a lint on this pattern should mention "if you are trying to create a struct that contains a reference to one of its fields ..." or alike, since so many times this is the cause.
